# How to use client_side_validation plugin with facebox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, modal-dialog, facebox

Today I installed client_side_validation plugin, everything works well until I encountered an issue, form validation cannot be accomplished in a modal window(facebox). Every time I clicked on submit button, it will close the modal window and update stuff regardless of what have been typed. Here is my code.

My form

```
<%= form_for (@task, :remote=>true, :validations => true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Remind me every"%>
   <%= f.text_field :frequency %>
   <%= f.label "days before" %>
      </div>
  <div class="field">
<br/>
<%= f.date_select :deadline, :start_year=>Time.now.year,:include_blank => true%>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 </div>  
<% end %>
```

My update function in controller

```
def update
   @task=Task.find(params[:id]);
   @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
   @task.reminded=true
   respond_to do |format| 
   if @task.save
    format.html
    format.js{
    render :update do |page|
      page << "jQuery.facebox.close();"
      yield(page) if block_given?
    end
    }
   else
   format.html
   format.js
   end
 end
end
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: well this is an old old post...and I think I haven't touched that project for a while now, but anyway I believe eventually I decided not to use facebox to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the javascript in page you want popup.

To test, require all the javascripts of your layout and if should be fine.

Works for me.